# Why do we need Ruby Serializer libraries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I've been experimenting with RubyOnRails API project. My project is not large, it is simply a toy project having a couple of tables with two associations.
All my responses are rendered n jon format using `oj` gem like this `render json: Oj.dump({...}), status: ok`. Everything works fine.

On the other hand we have a bunch of libraries such as `ActiveModelSerialization`, `jsonapi-rb`, `fast_jsonapi`, etc.

My question is: why do we need these libs if we simply `render json:...`? What do these libs do what `render json:...` can't do? Is it performance?
And my second question. Could you please suggest how I can benchmark these libs in Ruby (on Rails) (best practice)?

Answer (score 4):

It is simply a matter of code organization / reuse. Using libraries such as these helps keep the serialization constrained to a class which is responsible for it and therefore allows the controllers / models to remain cleaner.
Notice that some libraries also provide utilities such as allowing you to choose which fields are going to get displayed, useful DSLs and caching.

You can think of it as an application of the [S.O.L.I.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principe "Single Responsability": don't make a class (the controller) responsible for both rendering a request and serializing the data; delegate this work to another class responsible for this (a serializer).

Ruby has a class called Benchmark which you could use to test the speed of different serialization libraries. https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips may also prove useful. Lastly, you can see the output of the rails server, which contains the time to respond to the request, in ms, to figure out whether serialization is impacting the performance negatively, but it usually shouldn't.

Comment: As far as I understand, it is sort of misnomer. Actual serialisation (converting into JSON format) is done by either `json` or `oj`, while these libs are mainly responsible for transformation ActiveRecords, Associations, and etc into a specific format. For example, I didn't like `fast_jsonapi`, it's output is hellishly verbose and a coder must follow certain rules. In the end, do these libs also use json or oj? Or do they render using smth else?

Comment: If you take the concept of serialization literally (e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) then yes, it's a bit of a misnomer. Maybe a proper way of naming these libraries would be "Presenters" as they merely translate a hash to another hash in a different representation (I only have personally used ActiveModelSerializer). Whether they do some sort of data manipulation and *also* serialize to json goes beyond my knowlege. I'd need to dig in their source a bit. I think it might depend on the library. I do feel that @Mosaaleb has delineated this difference nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Serialization libraries mainly do two things: **preparing data** for serialization and the **actual serialization** (converting to JSON). Some serialization gems uses OJ instead of the standard JSON library for serialization, but you can also decide to go with OJ if you want to, check this example from [jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer/blob/88061bcfacf3f9800e02de9c2a7daffd3a3ded41/docs/json_serialization.md) gem on how to use it with OJ gem.

**Data preparation** Serialization gems offers a better separation of concerns and less redundant code, for example if you are sending some same data in different places you will have to write the response shape in every controller you are sending these data from. So instead you can define what (attributes, relationships, ....) in its corresponding serializer.

Another advantage of using serialization libraries, if you are working with the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/format/) format specifications which standardize how JSON responses format should look like.  Some libraries like AMS offer multiple adapters to choose from, other libraries like fastjson or jsonapi-serializers works only with JSON:API format.

Serialization libraries are just ruby code, you can use inheritance or composition to construct more complex JSON responses.

Check out this [article](https://buttercms.com/blog/json-serialization-in-rails-a-complete-guide) for serialization libraries comparison and benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question when I started exploring these libraries, especially since I don't do a lot of work with rails, and I found that most JSON:API serialization libraries I have seen are really for supporting the Rails/ActiveModel style of MVC web development. For development styles that don't fall into that category, these serialization libraries begin to lose their convenience.

As someone that does more API work, but still needs to work with JSON:API, The best serialization library I have found so far is [JSONAPI-SERIALIZER](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer), which was built by the **Netflix** team. It is lightweight, it doesn't force Active Record and Rails integration (even though it still supports it), and it's way faster than ActiveModelSerialization and other serialization libraries.

Another lightweight, non-rails-dependent, Ruby gem that pairs really well with [JSONAPI-SERIALIZER](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer) is the newer gem [EASY-JSONAPI](https://github.com/Curatess/easy-jsonapi/). It provides middleware for JSON:API compliance checking, a parser to work with requests, and a validator for already serialized responses. It might be useful for you if you prefer working with Oj to the other serialization libraries out there.

Comment: Welcome Joshua. Thanks for your informative posts but why do you writing the same [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14294408/joshua-demoss?tab=answers) continually

Comment: Hi Gurkan, if you are talking about me referencing easy-jsonapi and jsonapi-serializer, in my recent posts, it is because I think they are very helpful tools for developers who don't use rails but still use ruby, and I had the opportunity to help develop easy-jsonapi. It seems like the ruby world is dominated by rails tools, and it has been annoying for me in the past to find tools that aren't coupled to the rails / ActiveModel style of development. How would you suggest I go about referencing these tools in the future?

Comment: Sure you can and `JSON` is the most efficient way for many tool/framerowk/tech. But SO has a late answers section and your posts are triggered in this section. Of course you can share whatever you want but you can probably get a negative vote because of the same answers. By the way, I'm not the one who voted negatively :) As for Ruby, I don't have enough experience to give an idea about a framework other than its syntax. Although you will become professiaonal at the one language, I just recommend that you can think independently of language.

Comment: Gotcha gotcha, ya that makes sense. Thanks for the advice!! I'll keep it in mind for future posts! :)